# Password protect file and contents in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption

I've tried doing a lot of research on this topic, but haven't been able to find a good answer yet.

I know, on `mac` or `windows` to create an *encrypted zip* pretty easily, but for `python`, I cannot seem to find an easy way to take an `existing file` like `myfile.db`, and take the contents and encrypt it, then create another file, like `encrypted_myfile.db`

Does anyone have some samples they could share? or good tutorials on this?

I'm using `Python3`.

Thank you.

Comment: Check out `gnupg` package (after setting up a gpg key on the system). https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Creating_GPG_Keys

Comment: There are lots of options for encrypting file. [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+encrypt+file&gws_rd=ssl) has some good ideas.

Comment: There's also PyCrypto, which is quite powerful, but It doesn't have a simple "encrypt this file" method. It only provides the building blocks - the algorithms for encryption, hashing and random number generation.

Comment: @user5728855 - do you know of a library, or way to do the "simple" method?

Answer (score 0):

I did not write this myself, but have successfully used it:

```
from os import urandom
from hashlib import md5

from Crypto.Cipher import AES

def derive_key_and_iv(password, salt, key_length, iv_length):
    d = d_i = b''  # changed '' to b''
    while len(d) < key_length + iv_length:
        # changed password to str.encode(password)
        d_i = md5(d_i + str.encode(password) + salt).digest()
        d += d_i
    return d[:key_length], d[key_length:key_length+iv_length]

def encrypt(in_file, out_file, password, salt_header='', key_length=32):
    # added salt_header=''
    bs = AES.block_size
    # replaced Crypt.Random with os.urandom
    salt = urandom(bs - len(salt_header))
    key, iv = derive_key_and_iv(password, salt, key_length, bs)
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    # changed 'Salted__' to str.encode(salt_header)
    out_file.write(str.encode(salt_header) + salt)
    finished = False
    while not finished:
        chunk = in_file.read(1024 * bs) 
        if len(chunk) == 0 or len(chunk) % bs != 0:
            padding_length = (bs - len(chunk) % bs) or bs
            # changed right side to str.encode(...)
            chunk += str.encode(
                padding_length * chr(padding_length))
            finished = True
        out_file.write(cipher.encrypt(chunk))

def decrypt(in_file, out_file, password, salt_header='', key_length=32):
    # added salt_header=''
    bs = AES.block_size
    # changed 'Salted__' to salt_header
    salt = in_file.read(bs)[len(salt_header):]
    key, iv = derive_key_and_iv(password, salt, key_length, bs)
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    next_chunk = ''
    finished = False
    while not finished:
        chunk, next_chunk = next_chunk, cipher.decrypt(
            in_file.read(1024 * bs))
        if len(next_chunk) == 0:
            padding_length = chunk[-1]  # removed ord(...) as unnecessary
            chunk = chunk[:-padding_length]
            finished = True 
            out_file.write(
                bytes(x for x in chunk))  # changed chunk to bytes(...)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Don't roll your own password based key derivation function if you don't need to; even restricting yourself to built-ins + `pycrypto`, Python 3.4 and higher [provides a decent one in `hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac). Getting crypto right is hard, don't try to do any more of it than you absolutely have to.